# Cannondale neo eq electric bike manual

Tags: electric-bike, cannondale

Where can I find a manual for a Cannondale Neo Quick electric bike. I’ve searched online but can only find a supplementary Manual. This does not give any information about the functioning of the computerised control etc.

Comment: Have you checked with the place where you bought the bike?

Answer (score 3):

It will all be in the Bosch manuals for your specific control head (Purion etc) and drive unit. Bike brands may or may not include detailed instructions about the motor systems on their bikes in their manuals. Bike manuals are smoke and mirrors for the most part because they're written to cover as many bikes as possible, so having component-specific information about one model is the opposite of what they're trying to do. The Cannondale supplemental manuals are actually more useful than how most brands do it.